# How to listen to a event fired by a controller in controller with Sencha Touch2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have multiple controllers, assume them controller Main and Sub,
Controller Sub fires an event , I want to catch it on controller Main, 
what should I do? thanks!

**Edit:  I paste my code here**

in Sub Controller:

```
config: {

    control:    {
        'pinlist': {
            disclose: 'showPinDetails'                
        }                    
    }

} 


, showPinDetails: function(list, record) {
    console.log('showPinDetails');

    this.fireEvent('showPinDetails',list, record);

}
```

in Main Controller:

```
requires: [
            'MyApp.controller.Sub',
            ],  


config: {

    listeners: {
        'showPinDetails': 'showPinDetails',
    }
} , 
showPinDetails: function(list, record){
    console.log('showPinDetails');       
},
```

So, I just got the log 'showPinDetails' from Sub, rather from the two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Sub controller, suppose that you fired an event through something like this:

```js
yourComponent.fireEvent('my_event',this);
```

Then you have to define the listener and handler programmatically in your Main Controller. The **best practice** is:

```js
Ext.define('app.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
               yourComponent: 'enter your selector here, eg. #id'
        },
        control: {
               yourComponent: {
                 'my_event': 'my_event_handler'
               }
        }
    },
    my_event_handler: function() {
      //do whatever you want here
    })
});
```

Comment: "yourComponent: 'enter your selector here, eg. #id'" . but my component is a controller, it does not has an id!

Comment: if you just want to call a specific function of that controller directly, do this: `Ext.getApplication().getController('your_controller_name').my_event_handler()`

Comment: @ThiemNguyen why did you pass "this" in the call to fireEvent? I think it will just be available to your handler where I dont see you using it. Or does it change the scope the handler is fired in

Comment: `this` refers to **scope** of the function. So if you want to run some methods which are not in the same controller, you have to pass the reference of your component (to be processed later, somewhere...), that's how `this` is used

Answer (score 0):

In Sub controller, in one of the handler functions, you can write the below code.

```
....
btnClick : function() {
   myPanel.fireEvent('mycustomevent', this);
}
....
```

In the Main controller, you can listen for that event on some component like below,

```
......
listeners : {
    'mycustomevent' : function() {
             // ....
             // ....
     }
}
......
```

Comment: `myPanel` is just a container (for e.g) on which I am firing my custom event.

Comment: but at this situation, it is a controller, not a subclass of Container. I've paste my code above

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need a reference to your other controller. This can be done with:

`var other = YourAppName.app.getController('OtherController');`

Then in the `init`/`launch` method of your "listening" controller (or any other place that suits you) you can add an event listener:

```
other.on({
    myCustomEventName: function () {
        console.log('Hello World');
    }
});
```

If you are creating your sub controller manually and not by adding it to the controllers array in `app.js` then you need to add the listener after you have created the sub controller.